# Shortcut for Focusing Console Filter in Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm frequently needing to filter out my Chrome console during web development. Unfortunately every time I want to filter for a different term, I must manually click the search box. I don't see anything about a shortcut for focusing the filter bar in the [Chrome devtools shortcut docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/shortcuts/), is there a way to assign a shortcut to do this? This would make using the filter much master.

If there's an extension that will do it I'm also open to that.

OS: Windows 10

[image]

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: @Gantendo yes I am on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such shortcut in Chrome, so you have to invent your own.

You can use the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following AutoHotkey script will enable two shortcuts
(only when Chrome is active), first
<kbd>F9</kbd> to conserve the current mouse coordinates, and then
<kbd>F10</kbd> to generate a click at these coordinates:

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
X := Y := 0

#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
F9:: MouseGetPos, X, Y
F10:: Click, %X% %Y%
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: I'm thinking there's a way to do this that doesn't involve windows scripting, but rather some kind of javascript script that you can run in chrome.

Comment: That's not possible, since the Dev Tools aren't an HTML page, but are hard-coded in the Chrome program. There's no possibility to inject Javascript, nowhere to inject it into.

Comment: It may be possible to edit Chromium, but not Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

There is no keyboard hotkey for that field afaik.

I'd do something like this:

```
;https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm

HotKeySet("{F9}", "Coordinates")
HotKeySet("{F10}", "Clickit")

Global $aPos = MouseGetPos()

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func Coordinates()
    $aPos = MouseGetPos()
EndFunc

Func Clickit()
    Local $aPos2 = MouseGetPos()
    MouseMove($aPos[0],$aPos[1],0)
    Sleep(10)
    MouseClick("left")
    MouseMove($aPos2[0],$aPos[1],0)
EndFunc
```

It is an [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) script.

If you press <kbd>F9</kbd> the Coordinates function runs.
It saves the coordinates in a array called $aPos.

If you press <kbd>F10</kbd> the Clickit function runs.
It saves the current mouse coordinates in an array called $aPos2.
It moves the mouse to the coordinates saved in $aPos (saved earlier in the previous function) and clicks, and then moves back to the coordinates saved in $aPos2.

Move the mouse over the position of the console filter. Press F4. AutoIt will save the location. Continue doing whatever you were doing. When you want to type there again, press F3.

Over at https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm you can find a list of all the keys you can use instead of <kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>F10</kbd>.